# How to load json from csv of postgres to mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, csv

I using postgres and mysql . Now i want migrate data from postgres to mysql.
I export data from postgres to csv and then reimport it to mysql.

My csv export from postgres with name : test.csv . Column data type json of postgres.

Test.csv

```
id,name,data
"1","someName","{""email"": ""a@gmail.com"", ""country"": ""US""}"
```

And in mysql i using command reimport to mysql with same column

```
LOAD DATA  LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.csv'  INTO TABLE someTable  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

When i import it import success but column data is null . I don't know why
If i using commmand

```
LOAD DATA  LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.csv'  INTO TABLE someTable  fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"' escaped by '\'' lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

MYSQL thow me exception :

```
Invalid JSON text: "The document root must not be followed by other values." at position 4 in value for column 'someTable.data'.
```

How to import from csv with json column to mysql. Please help . Thanks you

Comment: You need to remove the double quotes `""` as that is not valid JSON. Possibly you can do this in the export, can you tell postgress to wrap columns in single quotes than it wont have to double quote the data

Comment: I using command : "COPY users TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER " > namefile.csv to export data. How to i remove double quotes ?

Comment: Try to process your CSV in any text processor and replace `""` with `\"`. If not then load your file into temptable with one column of TEXT type then parse loaded lines and save them into working table with another query.